# In MIPS,how to print a array in decreasing order

Tags: mips

result: .space   8

```
    .byte    0
```

After some procedures

result become 01234567

but i want to it become 76543210

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by correctly creating an array in the data segment. You also can use `.space` and then fill it in. It doesn't matter.

```
arrSize: .word     8
arr:     .word     0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Next, proceed to write the print routine. If you come up with a solution and you get stuck, post that and you'll likely receive help fixing the problem areas. If you need help getting started with MIPS coding, here are a few good resources:

[MIPS Architecture and Assembly Language](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/architecture/MIPSRef%28SPIM%29.html)

[Data and Text Segment](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/dataseg.html)

[MIPS Programmer's Guide](http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/education/lectures/TI1/materials/assemblylanguageprogdoc.pdf)